# Is there a way to make Firefox use macOS native picture-in-picture?

Tags: macos, firefox

I always make my apps fullscreen and Firefox's picture-in-picture does not carry across workspaces. Is it possible to make Firefox use the native macOS picture-in-picture API, like Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-picture-picture-firefox) official Firefox link. Should be pretty simple :)

Comment: Have you actually read the article? It just tells you how to use Firefox's implementation of picture-in-picture, but I don't want to use that. I want Firefox to use macOS's native picture-in-picture. They are not the same thing.